# Pandas Dataframe column will set to string but not integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to set the values in a Dataframe to the values from a separate dataframe. This works just fine when the source column is a string but the integer columns are not being copied, or throwing an error.

```
RentryDf=pd.DataFrame(index=tportDf.index.values,columns=tradesDf.columns)        
RentryDf.loc[:,'TRADER']=tportDf.loc[:,'TRADER']
RentryDf.loc[:,'CONTRACT_VOL']=tportDf.loc[:,'DELIVERY VOLUME']
```

the second line has no problem setting to the string names of trader but the third line stays NaN. I have tried the two lines of code to just see if they would work and even these dont work.

```
RentryDf.loc[:,'CONTRACT_VOL']=11
RentryDf.loc[:,'CONTRACT_VOL'].apply(lambda x: 11)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? It's easier to help with something to work with.

Comment: I solved my question while trying to recreate it (i guess i learned a good strategy!)

The problem was in my deceleration of the dataframe i was passing columns=tradesDf.columns rather than columns=tradesDf.columns.values.

I am pleased to have it fixed but does anyone know why this would cause the DF not to set the integer values but it would set string values?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question while trying to recreate it (i guess i learned a good strategy!)

The problem was in my deceleration of the dataframe i was passing `columns=tradesDf.columns` rather than `columns=tradesDf.columns.values`.

I am pleased to have it fixed but does anyone know why this would cause the DF not to set the integer values but it would set string values?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the bug, it works both for float64 and int64.

I guess the problem could be wrong indexing, since line 1 will create a DF with all value as NaN.